# How to set a GPIO pin to default HIGH before setting it to output?

Tags: gpio, rpi.gpio, relay, output

I have a raspberry pi connected to a Sainsmart 4-channel relay, where each relay is activated by a LOW signal.

When I set a GPIO pin to output, it defaults to LOW, which of course activates the relay for a split second before I can set it to HIGH. Is there any way to set the default output state before setting a pin to output mode?

Here is a very simplified version of my code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.OUT)

#pin is now outputting LOW by default

GPIO.output(11, GPIO.HIGH)
```

As you can see above, there is a split second between setting the pin to OUT and setting it to HIGH. During that time the pin is outputting LOW, which is the default state (If I try to set it HIGH before setting it to OUT, I get an error for trying to set the state of an input pin).

Having the pin output LOW even for a split second screws with what I'm trying to achieve. So basically all I want to do is have the pin default to HIGH when I set it to OUT.

Comment: Odd.  I thought most libraries set the level before setting the mode.  Please post your code.

Comment: I posted some code. The library does set it before switching to output; it just sets it low and doesn't seem to give me any option otherwise.

Comment: If you read the RPi.GPIO documentation I think it tells you what to do.

Comment: I think that `GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.OUT, inital = GPIO.HIGH)` is the best you're going to get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by [anonymoose's comment](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/63234/how-to-set-a-gpio-pin-to-default-high-before-setting-it-to-output#comment99907_63234) and RPi.GPIO's documentation [RPi.GPIO module basics](https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/BasicUsage/) setting a pin to output allows to specify an initial value:

> To set up a channel as an output:
>
> ```
> GPIO.setup(channel, GPIO.OUT)
> ```
>
> (where channel is the channel number based on the numbering system you have specified (BOARD or BCM)).
>
> You can also specify an initial value for your output channel:
>
> ```
> GPIO.setup(channel, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.HIGH)
> ```

Comment: Note the documentation under VOLTAGES https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/gpio/

Comment: Thanks, the correct answer was to use the optional `initial` argument, which I had overlooked.